# Wordpress, meta_filter_posts damaged the custom-menu widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

when i add this code to my `functions.php`

```
function meta_filter_posts( $query )
{
   if(is_tag() && is_main_query())
   {
        $currentTagId = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'rank_tag_'.$currentTagId.'');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
   }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'meta_filter_posts' );
```

my sidebar `custom menu`-widgets doesnt work anymore. 
The widgets show only the `widget-title` but not the `widget-content`.

The rest, e.g. the `text`-widgets are working normal.

But why? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

- When using `pre_get_posts`, you should always make sure that you target the front end only. `pre_get_posts` alters all type of queries front end **and** backend
- `is_tag()` and `is_main_query()` should be member variables of `$query`

You can do something like this

```
if(!is_admin() && $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query())
```